# VBA - how to go about the automation of checking the inputs (newbie here)

Tags: vba, automation, find

Specifically what I would want to do is find a way to check if a certain input in Sheet1 cell, is also found in sheet2.

Not knowledgeable with VBA so I tried recording macro

```
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Cells.Find(What:="asd", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Now instead of string "asd", I want the input in sheet1, below

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B1").Select
```

I tried changing "asd" to input in sheet1,

```
   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
   Cells.Find(What:=
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Range("B1").Select, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

but it's giving me an error.  Any one can please help how to go about this or recommend a different approach to resolve my problem.

Comment: What:=worksheets("Sheet1").range("b1").value, after:=worksheets("Sheet1").range("b1")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cells.Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Select
```

**EDIT:** As I told you in the comment

```
Dim MyCell as Range
Set MyCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

'This will check if it is found or not
If MyCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Did not find it"
Else
    MsgBox "Found it"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks.    My next setp would be After the macro, it should output a code in Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2"). say output 1 if value is found else 0.. Below is the code, need to add up and if else statement maybe for the output?______________________________________                                                                   Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub

Comment: You should declare a variable as Range and then set it equal to what you find. I will edit my answer to show you an example of the code.

Comment: Can I set the if else instead o message box in to value in a cell say :    If MyCell Is Nothing Then
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1" 
Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0" 
End If

Comment: Of course! I use the `MsgBox` as an example but you can do whatever you want in your `if statement` instead. By the way, you should write it: `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "1"` You do not need to use `Select` if you use `ActiveCell` right after. Also you should try to avoid select as much as possible, especially if you will run long codes. (If my answer satisfied you, could you validate it?)

Comment: Dim MyCell As Range
Set MyCell = Sheets("Admin Summary").Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet6").Range("B2").Value, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'This will check if it is found or not
If MyCell Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("Sheet6").Range("B3").Value = "0"
Else
    Sheets("Sheet6").Range("B3").Value = "1"
End If  :)

Comment: Its Working... THANKS A LOT

Comment: Glad to be helpful !

Comment: I'm just starting on this vba mcaro as i'm more on the statistical modeling and stuffs.  I'm starting to enjoy this.  Actually will use this to check consistencies of certain values among different documents. Documents are of different format, pdf excel and word, so will be pasting all the documents to different sheets of excel. then automate the checking of different values across the documents. easy to spot which document is inconsistent. easy to spot errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare strings in different sheets, just create a new button and add fallowing code:

```
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1") = Sheets("sheet2").Range("b1") then
   msgbox " string match"
Else
  msgbox " string don't match"
End If
```

This code will compare cell b1 from sheet1 to cell b1 from sheet2

Comment: The second sheet is unstructured so cant reference the sheet2.range.

Comment: What do you mean with sheet is unstructured?

Comment: no specific format as the sheet2 data comes from the pdf file which I just copied and pasted. the pd file has also no standard format, so I eed to use the find function to check if the specific value from sheet 1 can be found in sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the Instr function

```
Dim pos As Integer

pos = InStr(Sheets("sheet2").Range("b1"), Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1"))

If pos<> 0 then
   msgbox " string match"
Else
  msgbox " string don't match"
End If
```